# Исходники кодов шестого издания Подробного руководства по JS Дэвида Флэнегана

Tags: javascript

Кто может дать ссылку на исходники кодов шестого издания Подробного руководства по JS Дэвида Флэнегана

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Пожалуйста](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596805531/examples.zip)